# regexp. Find sub string in string

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like:

> q.0.0.0.1-1111, q.0.0.0.1.tt_0-1111, tes-00000000-1111, q.00.00.000.0.xx_0-1111

I have next regexp:

> (?:(?<=[^-\s]{4}.\d{3})|(?<=[^-\s]{7}))[^-]+(?=-)|(?<=-)[^-\s]+-

It work well with all cases except q.00.00.000.0.xx_0-1111

This part of regexp (?:(?<=[^-\s]{4}\d\d) in this string q.00.00.000.0.xx_0-1111 look for sub string like:

> .000.0.xx_0

But i expect what this regexp find:

> .0.xx_0

What wrong in my regexp and how i can fix it for getting result, which i expect?

Will be grateful for the help.

Comment: It is due to this lookbehind in the alternation `(?<=[^-\s]{7})` that it matches too match because this assertion is true *before* the first one that asserts 3 digits in a row. Is there any logic to it to get to the desired matches?

Comment: You could rule out a dot and 3 digits in the second assertion with a word boundary to prevent backtracking https://regex101.com/r/Xbjy2j/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird maybe in string should be  something like .0.xx_0 after .\d{3}. or row should start with char, dot and 2> digs

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes it works as i expect. Pls paste this to the answe. I accept it and vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern matches too much due to the second alternation that can match before the first one that requires to match 3 digits.

For this scenario, you could limit the second assertion using a word boundary, and then assert that there are no 3 digits in a row:

```
 (?:(?<=[^-\s]{4}\d{3})|\b(?<=[^-\s]{7})(?![.\d]*\d\d\d))[^-]+(?=-)|(?<=-)[^-\s]+-
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJTL5d/1)

Comment: its broken when i have string like q.0.000.000.0.xx_0-1111 on part of string with have 3 or mo chars after first q.0. It is posible to search any number of chars?

Comment: @MrOldSir In Python re you can not use an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion. How are you using this pattern? Do you use where you can also use a replacement, or can you only have a match only? Which part of `q.0.000.000.0.xx_0-1111` should be matched?

Comment: i use this pattern in re.sub, for cutting sub string for base string. re.sub(
            pattern= (?:(?<=[^-\s]{4}\d{3})|\b(?<=[^-\s]{7})(?![.\d]*\d\d\d))[^-]+(?=-)|(?<=-)[^-\s]+-,
            repl='',
            string='one of string from example'
        )

Comment: @MrOldSir  Question, are these strings the only string on the line, or are they part of a larger string? Do they always start with  `q` and do you use `0` and `1` or are these examples? So if I also look at the examples of the previous question and the current answer, it looks like this https://regex101.com/r/B8gvNF/1 Can you update the regex101 link with the expected results?

Comment: it is only single string, not part of some another string. this string always start from a-z,A-Z. 1 and 0 it is examples. real data may any digit

Comment: it regexp always should take fist part of string and part with -xxxx  like: q.0.0.0.1-1111 -> q.0.0.0-1111, q.0.0.0.1.tt_0-1111->q.0.0.0-1111, q.0.0000.00000.0.xx_0-1111 > q.0.0000.00000-1111, so it should be any numbers of chars or digits in first part of string. Always one condition. first part of string it all chars up to 4 points in a row and second part, it is -xxxx. All between that should be cutting

Comment: @MrOldSir Like this? https://regex101.com/r/CxmaPT/1 See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bA6dNR)

Comment: yes. it cool and work well with all cases. Many thanks.